# Google Oauth2: when chorme-app closed in mobile, it logout

Tags: php, mobile, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

```
  $client = new Google_Client();
  $client->setApplicationName('Name of app');
  $client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);  
  $client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
  $client->addScope(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);
  $client->setApprovalPrompt('auto');
  $client->setAccessType("offline");  

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
  echo "success";
} else {
  $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/oauth2callback.php';
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

On Desktop:
when i close browser, it remembers my login data and i do not have to login again.

On Mobile:
When i close the chorme app, i have to login to access google service.

I guess that mobile device do not keep $_SESSION['access_token'] and code parameter.
That's why it has to create auth again.

```
$client->createAuthUrl();
```

Is there any way to keep login in mobile device, even if i close the chrome app(or firefox)?

"Refresh Token", "access Token expired" they have nothing to do with this problem.

Comment: Access tokens expire after an hour.   if your not storing the refresh token locally and then loading it into a session var the next time the app runs.  Its going to request access again.

Comment: @DaImTo I actually already set refresh token and it works with all browsers(chrome, firefox and safari) in Desktop. I also thought it is because of that google expire the accestoken and do not refresh it.
Even though i close the chorme-app in 10 seconds and when i open the app again direct, i have to log in again. It means i have it lost the seccsion for access_token or code for auth...

Answer (score 0):

First thing i want to say is i have no exprence with how this works in a chrom extension.   With desk top app you can store the refresh token on your machine and load it in latter.  I dont know if you can do that with Chrome-app

That being said make sure you have some where in your code where it loads the refresh token in to your client object. Then if your access token has expired you can do

```
$client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
```

Which will make your code refresh token access token.

```
function getOauth2Client() {
    try {
        
        $client = buildClient();
        
        // Set the refresh token on the client. 
        if (isset($_SESSION['refresh_token']) && $_SESSION['refresh_token']) {
            $client->refreshToken($_SESSION['refresh_token']);
        }
        
        // If the user has already authorized this app then get an access token
        // else redirect to ask the user to authorize access to Google Analytics.
        if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
            
            // Set the access token on the client.
            $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);                 
            
            // Refresh the access token if it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {              
                $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                $client->setAccessToken($client->getAccessToken()); 
                $_SESSION['access_token'] = $client->getAccessToken();              
            }           
            return $client; 
        } else {
            // We do not have access request access.
            header('Location: ' . filter_var( $client->getRedirectUri(), FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

I would love to hear if this helps I didn't know you could even do chrom-apps with php I may have to try.

Code ripped from [Oauth2Authentication.php](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-APIs-PHP-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Calendar%20API/v3/Oauth2Authentication.php)